# WebBrowser absolutely unresponsive towards CSS's background-color property

Tags: c#, html, css, wpf

The syntax & values to my knowledge are alright. See below.

```css
* { 
  overflow: hidden; 
  background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, .9); 
  color: rgb(242, 238, 229); 
  font-size: 18px; 
  font-family: Segoe UI,...;
}
```

`background-color` is the only property that seems to remain neglected. `!important` had no influence.

Here's the boilerplate HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='data:text/css;charset=UTF-8,{0}'>
  </head>
    <body>
      {1}
    </body>
</html>
```

*(If you're wondering what the `{0,1}`'s are, I'm formatting this in a C# WPF app, then navigating the HTML code towards an embedded WebBrowser)*

*The 0 corresponds to URI encoded CSS, which works as intended*.

For reference, here's my code within my WPF application:

```cs
TextRange rng = new TextRange(
    TextEntry.Document.ContentStart,
    TextEntry.Document.ContentEnd);

string cssString = ":not(h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6) { font-size: 11px; } * { overflow: hidden; background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, .9); color: rgb(242, 238, 229); font-family: Segoe UI...; }";

string htContent = string.Format("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'" 
                   + "href='data:text/css;charset=UTF-8,{0}'></head><body>{1}</body></html>",
                   Uri.EscapeUriString(cssString),
                   Markdig.Markdown.ToHtml(rng.Text));
```

No matter how specific I get with the `background-color` property, it will remain unresponsive sadly.

This is the xaml of the WebBrowser, if it helps.

```xml
<WebBrowser x:Name="Markdown" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="406" Margin="16,36,-9,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="800" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
```

All other posts I could find about this were because of an element somewhat overriding the style, though, due to how boilerplate this HTML & CSS is, I couldn't find anything of that nature.

Comment: Inlining a style property into the body element doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try newest browser control ([WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/wpf)) instead, it might work

Comment: So is this an issue with the WebBrowser then? How do you know?

Comment: I do not know, but we had a lot of issues with the default Wpf WebBrowser at work and I just want to advise you not use it. Take a look into samples https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/tree/master/SampleApps/WebView2WpfBrowser and decide what do you need, to battle with the old, outdated embedded browser in Wpf or use the latest Chromium based browser released by Microsoft despite the fact it is still a bit raw.

Comment: I'll take a look into this. I appreciate it.

Comment: Do you by chance know how to load my HTML string into this? Trying to set the source property always yells that the URI scheme is invalid when I attempt to encode it all.

Comment: To add on, I don't know what to set as the source property. Since I have no HTML files, only a string of html content.

Comment: I'll be damned. It was the control, thanks for your advice! Cheers.